# Conditionally fire trigger to invoke lambda in AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a S3 bucket that when it receives a json file it fires a trigger to invoke a lambda that processes the file.  I don't not want to invoke the lambda however for every file.  Only certain files where an key - value within the json is of a certain value.  For example, if the json contains "process":True then invoke the lambda but if "process": False then do not invoke the lambda.  There are millions of files sent daily so I do not want to add this logic to the lambda itself or it will be invoked unnecessarily many times.

Comment: I believe you can filter the Lambda trigger using filename patterns (prefix/suffix). Do you have the option of changing the producer of the json files so that it adds the prefix 'process_' or some such thing?

Comment: Yes, that is an option however the files are sent from third party and may be difficult to them to change.  Thank you for the suggestion though.